# children.toArray() - TS2339: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'... - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, key, children

I'm creating a TypeScript component/wrapper that adds a divider between each child:

```js
import React, { FC, Children } from 'react'

const DividedChildren: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Children.toArray(children).map((node, index) => {
        if (index === 0) return node
        return (
          <Fragment key={node.key}> // TS Error, but code works fine
            <div className="divider" />
            {node}
          </Fragment>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
```

However, I'm getting a TypeScript error when I try to move the child's `key` into his new container:
`TS2339: Property 'key' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'.   Property 'key' does not exist on type 'string'.`

##### How can I type-safely move each item's key to its new container?

Comment: Had the same problem when accessing child properties.

Property 'props' does not exist on type 'ReactChild'.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get around this specific error by casting `node` as a `ReactElement` type.

```
Children.toArray(children).map((node: React.ReactElement, index) => { //...
```